# How to bind a blur event to a live click event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have this function:

```
$('input#auto_results').bind('blur', function(e) {
    $('.result').bind('click', function() {
        return;
    });
    $('#results_container').hide();                                       
});
```

Basically, I would like the #results_container to hide on blur UNLESS an element with the class .result is clicked.

The above function does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem with your code:

What you're trying to do, is attaching a `click` event handler on `.result` in the event handler of another event (`blur`).

Your code will do nothing except attaching this `click` handler that basically does nothing.

---

### Simple option:

The `blur` event will be triggered first, and the `click` on `.results` second, so this is not an easy situation.

The simplest way you can do this is:

```
$('input#auto_results').blur(function () {
    $('#results_container').hide();
});

$('.result').click(function () {
    $('#results_container').show();
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AQ3P/1/)

So just hiding the container, an on click, show it again. Results in a small blink.

---

### Timeout option:

Another option I can think of, is setting a small timeout when the `blur` is triggered, and on the click event of `.results`, cancel it. In this example, I store the timeout on `body` with the `.data()` function, you could store it on a more logical element, this is just a demonstration:

```
$('input#auto_results').blur(function () {
    var cucc=setTimeout(function () {
        $('#results_container').hide();
        $('body').removeData('blurTimeout');
    }, 100);
    $('body').data('blurTimeout', cucc);
});

$('.result').click(function () {
    var cucc=$('body').data('blurTimeout');
    if (typeof cucc != 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(cucc);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzzbK/1/)